# Unable to access reference of list when contained element changes

Tags: javers

Below code simply creates two objects with two lists having same object marked with id only the content of the element is changed. The diff object generates a diff without any reference to parent list element but rather to the actual rop

```
    public class JaversTest {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        User u1 = new User();
        User u2 = new User();

        Email e1 = new Email();
        e1.setId("id1");
        e1.setMail("Vikrant5mahajan@gmail.com");

        Email e2 = new Email();
        e2.setId("id1");
        e2.setMail("Vikrant6mahajan@gmail.com");

        u1.setEmails(Collections.singletonList(e1));
        u2.setEmails(Collections.singletonList(e2));

        Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build();
        Diff diff = javers.compare(e1, e2);
        System.out.println(diff.prettyPrint());
      }

      @Data
      public static class User {
        List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<>();
      }

      @Data
      public static class Email {
        @Id
        String id;
        String mail;
      }
    }
```

The output i get is

```
1. ValueChange{globalId:'com.practo.test.api.diff.JaversTest$Email/id1', property:'mail', oldVal:'Vikrant5mahajan@gmail.com', newVal:'Vikrant6mahajan@gmail.com'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JaVers diff is perfectly right. I'm not sure what you expect but in your snippet you have created two versions of an email object, and then you compare them. Since the `mail` field is changed, you get the ValueChange.

What else could you get from the diff engine? Your emails have no references to users or lists, so, obviously, javers is unaware of them.

Btw, your mapping is wrong. Email is a typical Value Object not an Entity, try to remove `@Id` ann.

Comment: It is an entity in my case since it also is going to have unique id. Also regarding the requirement i just wanted to know the link back to actual link from the valuechange.